# Django accessing foreign key method in models

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to write a method in my models that is able to access a foreign key data. This is my codes:

**models.py:**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Normal")

class studentFund(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def subTotal(self):
        if self.student.type == "Normal"
            return self.rate
        else:
            return (self.rate * 2)
```

The above gets me a syntax error. Is there a way to do this so that I can easily calculate the "subTotal" in my models instead of in views?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of `if self.student.type == "Normal"`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony You mean a colon not a semicolon

Comment: oh my, how could I have missed the colon! that fixed it, thanks  alot!

Answer (score 3):

As guys pointed out, you are missing a colon in `if` statement.

Think about it, when it's SyntaxError, you have something wrong with your Python code, not with Django or whatever you are working on. It just means that the Python parser is unable to parse your source code.